# Represent ng-model in a controller

Tags: angularjs

I am developing application using AngularJS and ASP.Net MVC...

In my view, I have used `ng-repeat=u in users` in a `div`. Inside it, I set the `ng-model` in a textbox as `ng-model=u.fName` where `fName` is database field.

My question is, how I can represent the `ng-model=u.fName` in the angular controller??

For example, I tried to use `$scope.n.fName` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that u is only existing in ng-repeat block.
If you want to show/access to value changed by textbox outside of block, you should access via users again with another ng-repeat block:

```
<li ng-repeat="u in users">{{u.fName}}</li>
```

Or add ng-change="change(u)" to your textbox to get u anytime it's changed.

```
<input ng-model="u.fName" ng-change="change(u)" />
```

[Plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mPPsezOJeA4N2yMhxcre?p=info)

Comment: Thank you. How I can represent it in the `change` function?

Comment: See this example for show/access u: https://plnkr.co/edit/mPPsezOJeA4N2yMhxcre?p=info